# Redirigir a una página de error desde un controllador de AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Con el **controller** estoy alimentando el **templateUrl** con los datos de los archivos **json** que busca mediante el **id**, pero al un archivo **json** no existir el **templateUrl** queda vacío obviamente. Lo que quiero es que me ayuden a implementarle al **controller** una función de **error** para cuando no encuentre un archivo **json** me redirija a la ruta **otherwise** del **ngRoute** que es la que tengo con un **templateUrl** de **error404**. También sucede cuando en le navegador coloco una url con **id** que no existe, por que obviamente no encontró el archivo **json**. Espero que puedan ayudarme, de antemano ¡Muchas gracias!

```
.when('/items/:id',{
  templateUrl: 'items-details.html',
  controller: 'ItemDetailsCtrl',
  controllerAs: 'itemDetails'
})
.otherwise({
  redirectTo: '/error404'
});



app.controller('ItemDetailsCtrl', ['$scope','$routeParams','$http', function($scope,$routeParams,$http){
    $http.get('/json/items/' + $routeParams.id + '.json').success(function(data){
      $scope.item = data;
    });
  }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto lo podrías conseguir capturando el error de la petición con `$http.get` y usando el servicio `$location` para navegar a la página de error.

La implementación de tu controlador quedaría así:

```
app.controller('ItemDetailsCtrl', ['$scope','$routeParams','$http', '$location',
function($scope,$routeParams,$http, $location){
    $http.get('/json/items/' + $routeParams.id + '.json').then(
        function(resp)  
        {
            $scope.item = resp.data;
        }, function(err){
            $location.path("/error404");
        });
}]);
```

#### Actualización 03/05/2016: para responder a las preguntas de los comentarios

**"Sigue accediendo al templateUrl aunque no exista el archivo .json"**

Ese es el comportamiento de **ngRoute**, primero carga la plantilla y después ejecuta el controlador. Además debe ser así porque se comparte la misma plantilla para las distintas peticiones que se realizan al controlador cambiando los parámetros por lo que la plantilla podría estar cacheada

**"Ahora el templateUrl no se alimenta con los datos de los archivos .json existentes"**

- En principio debería funcionar correctamente aunque si que he detectado un error en el código porque al obtener la respuesta del `$http.get` hay que acceder a la propiedad ´data´ porque lo que devueve en el promise es la respuesta completa
- También es posible que te falte definir la ruta para la página de error

  ```
  .when('/error404', {
      templateUrl : 'pages/error404.html'
  })
  ```

Por cierto, he creado [este Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/J61amxT4FqvzIo4Oy0SC?p=preview) donde lo puedes ver funcionando

Comment: Gracias por responder @rsciriano eres el único que me ayuda aquí lol. La implementación del controller que me enseñaste no me funciona correctamente, sigue accediendo al templateUrl aunque no exista el archivo .json y ahora el templateUrl no se alimenta con los datos de los archivos .json existentes, qué crees que sea ? y Google Chrome no me lanza ningún error para ver por qué es.

Comment: Hola @AdrianoJosué, he actualizado mi respuesta para intentar responder a tus preguntas. Saludos

Comment: Tengo todo el código correctamente escrito y todo funciona bien excepto que cuando no encuentra el archivo **.json** no me redirecciona a la página de error y tengo definida la ruta para la página de error y todo esta bien, no entiendo que sucede.

Comment: Hola @AdrianoJosué, quizás mirado mi código veas algo que te ayude. También podrías modificar el Plunker con tu código para reproducir el problema y poder ayudarte (o compartir tu código en GitHub). Saludos